# Hide div element with jquery on some wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to hide certain divs for certain pages on my wordpress page. If I just use css it will hide this div in all my pages, which I do not want. I know how to do this for regular websites but not sure how to use this code for wordpress pages.

```
$(function(){
  if (window.location.pathname == "mywebsite/Videos.html"||window.location.pathname == "url2.html"||window.location.pathname == "url3.html") {
        $('#navleft').hide();
  } else {
        $('#navleft').show();
  }
```

});

Im trying to add a similar code to this on my functions.php page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this in CSS only.

#### Find you're page(s) ID

[Check the page source code](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm), in the body tag there is a unique class with the page ID.

```
<body class="[...] page-id-XXX [...]">
```

Or, in your admin dashboard, go to Pages section.
Find you're page and [look the edit link](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/), you'll find a post parameter (`post=`). **It's the page ID**.

#### Change you're CSS file

You could add those lines in your CSS file

```
.page-id-XX #navleft,
.page-id-YY #navleft {
  display: none;
}
```

where `XX` is your *Videos.html* **page ID** and so on.

Comment: ok thank you, let say my page that Im trying to modify is called shop, how would I put this in the id

Comment: and what if im choosing a class div instead of id

Comment: For the `page-id-XX`, you don't have to do anything. Wordpress already did for you.
Each page of your website has a unique class in the `<body>` tag.
Then, you can hide anything : `.page-id-XX .class, .page-id-XX #id`

Comment: so do I replace xx with shop? but if its a class why is it page page-id?

Comment: It's just a class name but this class name represents the page ID. So `page-id-XX`.
The XX part is the real shop page number ID. You can find it in the `<body>` tag (look the source code) and also in the backoffice > Pages section and check the [edit shop page URL](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/), you'll find a post parameter (`post=XX`).

Comment: ok i know Im asking too many question but where can I find the source code for the shop page on my wordpress

Comment: [How to view the HTML source code of a web page](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JavaScript to achieve this. Wordpress provides many css classes in body element that you can use. The page ID class is unique for every page, so you can create some css rules like this:

```
body.page-id-26 #navleft {
    display: none;
}

body.page-id-29 #navleft {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: right click on the page and click over "View Page Source" if you are on Mozilla Firefox then find the body tag and check the classes.